# ERROR while downloading youtube videos from terminal

Tags: 11.04, command-line, youtube

I installed youtube-dl very recently and
when I tried to download a particular video using its url as (youtube-dl url),the following error occured:

> Error "no fmt_url_map or conn information found in video info" with
>   specific video

My youtube-dl version: 2011.01.30

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the latest youtube-dl from http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/

Open a terminal by pressing (ctrl + alt + t ) and type or better copy and paste from here the rows below:

```
wget http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/download.html -o youtube-dl
chmod 700 youtube-dl
./youtube-dl  ...
```

if it works please fill a youtube-dl bug, open a terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-bug youtube-dl
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

to update it, and try some video again.